# Stating affiliation when recommending a 3rd party software/tool

Tags: discussion

I have experienced that when writing an answer, it is generally a good practise to state the affiliation (or not) with the developer of the 3rd party app/tool if one is recommended as part of the answer.

However, I'd like to know if this is something that needs to be followed to the letter ***every, single, time***?

There are some popular and very widely used tools (most of them generally macOS/iOS exclusive) which users new to Apple ecosystem may not be aware of. I am talking about the apps/tools which are so popular that it practically won't make a difference for them whether I recommend it or not.

So my question is, is it necessary to clearly state my (absence of) affiliation with said app/tool? In the answer, I tend to mention that the app/tool is popular/widely used, but I feel that stating the affiliation may not be needed in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [relevant Help Center article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) states:

> #### How not to be a spammer
>
> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

It's not explicitly mentioned, but this means that if you're *not* affiliated with a product you recommend, you're not required to disclose so. Especially if it's a widely used tool like Sublime or BBEdit; when done repeatedly, that would quickly be perceived as noise, distracting from the main content.
<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with either of those.</sub>

Comment: Ah, the contradiction!

Comment: Yeah, that was intentional :)